# unsupported Encoding exception with httpclient

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use httpclient in my android app.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://@@@@/users/register");

List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nickname", "prout"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "@@@@@@gmail.commm"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "@@@@@@"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
```

The error message is on the last line : unsupported Encoding exception

Do you have any ideas to fix it ?

thanks

Comment: please post the stack trace of the exception, and the exception message (if any)

Comment: What's the full error message you are receiving? (with exception class name and stack trace) Are there any restrictions on what kinds of encodings you can put into the post entity?

Comment: when i'm try to build i have this message : Error:(157, 40) error: unreported exception UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Seems like one of your code lines throws this exception. You have to either catch it with  a try/catch statement or throw it.